# Выражение с сумой на C++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

[image: Выражение]Всем привет,можете пожалуйста хотя бы обьяснить как это решать?

Comment: Создай цикл и переменную, накапливающую результаты деления

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ладно, такое задание не часто встречается. Не утерпел :), ведь точно будут накручивать тремя циклами за O(n^2)...

```
double Sum(unsigned int n)
{
    assert(n >= 1); 

    double harm = 0, sum = 0, fact = 1;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) sum += (fact *= k)/(harm += 1./(1.+k));

    return sum;
}
```